# Is there a change in GraphQL Schema between JSS version 11 and 14?

Tags: jss, upgrade, graphql

I am currently using sitecore 9.0.2 and have installed JSS to query the data using graphQL queries. I use below features of JSS:

1. Querying data using http://sitecore.local/sitecore/api/graph/items/master
2. Query data using http://sitecore.local/sitecore/api/graph/items/master/ui

Apart from the above use case I don't use JSS for any other purpose. If I upgrade to sitecore 10, will there be any change in contract to query the data using graphQL.

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: I am not aware of any significant changes, but the best way to confirm this would be to introspect the schema of each version and diff, using something like the graphql-cli.
https://github.com/Urigo/graphql-cli/blob/master/docs/MIGRATION.md#get-schema-is-no-longer-available